# How to Monitor Tomcat 7.0 With Zabbix 3.2 | Tomcat Monitoring on Zabbix

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat7, monitoring, zabbix

I have Successfully installed Zabbix 3.2 server on ubuntu 14.0 The Z on the host is green.Unfortunately, JMX is red.

Zabbix Server : 192.168.1.112
Linux Server with tomcat : 12.8.9.20

Followed 
https://www.zabbix.com/forum/showpos...00&postcount=7

Step 1: Create a host or add JMX interface to existing. 
Step 2: Add the Zabbix agent to tomcat server (12.8.9.20) 
Step 3: Configure the Zabbix agent 
Step 4: install the Os Linux template. 
Step 5: On zabbix Server install zabbix-java-gateway
Step 6: The following are the only 3 changes that I've made in the file
/etc/zabbix/zabbix_java_gateway.conf
... 
LISTEN_IP="192.168.1.112" ( / Not sure about this should i keep the ip address to 127.0.0.1) 
LISTEN_PORT=10052
START_POLLERS=5

So the Question should i install java-gateway on tomcat machine .
What other settings I have to configure ?

Comment: The forum thread link seems to be broken currently. Also, you do not need a Zabbix agent for JMX monitoring. Instead, it should be possible for Java gateway to connect to the monitored application just like an app like jconsole would. Please see official documentation on JMX monitoring for more details: https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.2/manual/config/items/itemtypes/jmx_monitoring .

Answer (score 2):

I have the exact same problem with the similar versions of:

- Ubuntu 14.04
- Zabbix 3.2
- Tomcat 6 and 7
- OpenJDK 7u121-2.6.8-1ubuntu0.14.04.1 on both servers (Tomcat server and Zabbix server)

And IPv4 networking:

- Tomcat Server IP: 192.168.56.38
- Zabbiz Server IP: 192.168.56.119

After a lot (really a lot) of testing, googling, tcpdumping, stracing, etc, I finally change the `catalina.sh` file wit this conf:

```
CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS \
                -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote \
                -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=12345 \
                -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false \
                -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false \
                -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=192.168.56.38"
```

Where the IP `192.168.56.38` is the **tomcat** IP address (not the zabbix IP address) and finally it worked!!

I went through all these links:

- https://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/jconsole-jmx-remote-access-on-tomcat/
- http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/monitoring.html
- https://germanogiudici.wordpress.com/2013/03/21/how-to-connect-jconsole-to-a-remote-tomcat-on-a-linux-machine-resolving-connection-refused-issue/

but all of them indicates to use the remote server address (zabbix in my case) but never worked.

I suspecteded that it was a Zabbix issue, but I could replicate the same problem with Tomcat + Remote JConsole, so it's a Java thing.  I really don't understand why, but it's working with the conf mentioned

Comment: Sorry, but where is locate catalina.sh?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Please find the attachment of the error message. 
1.) Do I have to enable this step on tomcat server which I'm trying to monitor ?

java \

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=12345 \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false \
-jar /usr/share/doc/openjdk-6-jre-headless/demo/jfc/Notepad/Notepad.jar
```

2.) Do i need make any other change zabbix_agentd.conf or any other file. I change javagatewaypoll

```
#       Size of history index cache, in bytes.
ption: StartEscalators
#       Number of pre-forked instances of escalators.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Range: 0-100
# Default:
# StartEscalators=1

### Option: JavaGateway
#       IP address (or hostname) of Zabbix Java gateway.
#       Only required if Java pollers are started.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Default:
JavaGateway=127.0.0.1

### Option: JavaGatewayPort
#       Port that Zabbix Java gateway listens on.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Range: 1024-32767
# Default:
JavaGatewayPort=10052

### Option: StartJavaPollers
#       Number of pre-forked instances of Java pollers.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Range: 0-1000
# Default:
# StartJavaPollers=0
StartJavaPollers=5

### Option: StartVMwareCollectors
#       Number of pre-forked vmware collector instances.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Range: 0-250
# Default:
# StartVMwareCollectors=0

### Option: VMwareFrequency
#       How often Zabbix will connect to VMware service to obtain a new data.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Range: 10-86400
# Default:
# VMwareFrequency=60

### Option: VMwarePerfFrequency
#       How often Zabbix will connect to VMware service to obtain performance data.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Range: 10-86400
# Default:
# VMwarePerfFrequency=60
```

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration file says that JMX is running on port 10052. Check on which port the JMXis running and make sure that this JMX port is opened bidirectional connection with Zabbix agent and Zabbix server. If the port is not opened, request your network team to open the bidirectional connection.